# Does JENA API support OWL 2?

Tags: jena, owl, owl-api, jena-rules

May I know if Apahe JENA supports OWL 2 syntax in Java? It does mentioned that in the documentation (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) it only provide limited cardinality restrictions. I would like to confirm this from the experts.

Comment: The experts would be the people who wrote the documentation that confirms the answer your looking for :)

Comment: No, it doesn't support full OWL 2. And yes, I can confirm the documentation. It's mostly up to date. By the way, you could still add the RDF triples by hand to build the OWL constructs, you just don't have the convenience API methods in Jena. Or you use OWL API given that the OWL is made of axioms and not RDF triples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apache Jena](https://github.com/apache/jena) does *not* support OWL2, only OWL11 through [org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.java) interface. See also [documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/).

But you still can work with OWL2 in Jena using some external jena-based APIs and tools, e.g. [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api), that is [OWL-API](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi)-api(**v5**) impl over Jena.

In ONT-API there are two main OWL2 view of data, which encapsulate the same RDF Graph: `com.github.owlcs.ontapi.jena.model.OntModel` and `com.github.owlcs.ontapi.Ontology` (*in older versions (ONT-API:**v1.x.x**) these classes have names `ru.avicomp.ontapi.jena.model.OntGraphModel` and `ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyModel` respectively*).

The [com.github.owlcs.ontapi.jena.model.OntModel](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/owlcs/ontapi/jena/model/OntModel.java) view is a full analogue of Jena `org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel`, it is the facility to work with triples.
And the [com.github.owlcs.ontapi.Ontology](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/owlcs/ontapi/Ontology.java) view is an extended `org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology`, the facility to work with axiomatic data, that is backed by the `com.github.owlcs.ontapi.jena.model.OntModel` view and vice-versa.

For example, the following snippet:

```
    String uri = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049750";
    String ns = uri + "#";
    OntModel m = OntModelFactory.createModel()
            .setNsPrefixes(OntModelFactory.STANDARD).setNsPrefix("q", ns);
    m.setID(uri);
    OntClass c = m.createOntClass(ns + "c");
    OntObjectProperty p = m.createObjectProperty(ns + "p");
    OntIndividual i = c.createIndividual(ns + "i");
    m.createObjectComplementOf(m.createObjectUnionOf(c, m.getOWLThing(),
            m.createObjectSomeValuesFrom(p, m.createObjectOneOf(i))));
    m.write(System.out, "ttl");
```

will produce the following ontology:

```
@prefix q:     <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049750#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049750>
        a       owl:Ontology .

q:c     a       owl:Class .

q:p     a       owl:ObjectProperty .

q:i     a       owl:NamedIndividual , q:c .

[ a                 owl:Class ;
  owl:complementOf  [ a            owl:Class ;
                      owl:unionOf  ( q:c owl:Thing
                                     [ a                   owl:Restriction ;
                                       owl:onProperty      q:p ;
                                       owl:someValuesFrom  [ a          owl:Class ;
                                                             owl:oneOf  ( q:i )
                                                           ]
                                     ]
                                   )
                    ]
] .
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the lengthy explanation. I really appreciate it. Thank you again.